# Why anchor(<a ) style a:visited color applies to all the anchor tags in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, anchor

I need a crack to allow a:visited to set to Purple color only on clicked anchor link.

It works fine with IE but do not work with Firefox or Chrome.

**Try this in Firefox**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
a {color: blue;}
a:visited {color:purple;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Link One</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="#" target="_blank">Link Two</a></b></p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Question**: When you click Link One, only Link One should turn in purple color or as visited. Link Two should remain Blue.

Tried many changes nothing helped, please avoid love/hate order and unnecessary replies.

Thanks in advance. :)

**Edit:** Please check href, this is how application handles and performs action on **onclick**

Comment: It might be because link 1 and link 2 are the same link. Try changing the href of link 2 to see if that's the issue

Comment: Because it's the browser that applies the visited state; it's the same link from the browser's point-of-view.

Comment: 'visited' is based on the 'href' attribute. It's the same in your two anchors !

Comment: Please check the update Edit in question, this is the requirement to provide action as #

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way to do this. The visited status of a link is determined by the URL it links to and the browser history.

The only work around I can think of would be to:

1. Give each link an identifier
2. Bind a JavaScript event handler to each link that sets a cookie containing the id of the clicked link
3. When the page loads, checking for the existence of said cookie and adding a class to elements with matching ids.
4. Setting the purple colour on elements that are members of that class instead of on `:visited`.

Comment: Isn't it now a security feature that :visited links are only stylable in certain ways? [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

Comment: Would adding a querystring work?  Like `default.aspx?1` and `default.aspx?2`

Comment: @Paulie_D — Yes. You can't do anything that will change their dimensions. Colour changes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because both your links are pointing to the same page. The browser keeps track of which pages you visited not which link you clicked on.

Since showing links as visited or not visited is highly dependent on browser history which means its also dependent on which browser the user is going to use, its better to track visited links using cookies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
a {color: blue;}
a.visited {color:purple;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p><b><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="http://www.msn.com" target="_blank">MSN</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a></b></p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(){
        $.cookie($(this).attr('href'),'visited');
        markAllVisitedLinks();
    });

    markAllVisitedLinks=function(){
        $("a.visited").removeClass("visited");
        $("a").each(function(){
            if($.cookie($(this).attr('href'))=='visited')
            {
                $(this).addClass("visited");
            }
        });
    }

    markAllVisitedLinks();

});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

the jquery.cookie.js plugin is available at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: TRUE, but when my application is closed, history still exists. So, even I provide different url in href, once clicked, the issue comes again.
But, why same is not true with IE.?

Answer (score 0):

Like other have said it's because both of your links have the same 'href' attribute value. This makes the browser see it as the same link. Therefore if you click on link 1 the browser will see it as link 1 and link 2 have both been visited. If you change them to have different 'href' attribute values that should solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
a {color: blue;}
a:visited {color:purple;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><b><a href="default.asp" target="_blank">Link One</a></b></p>
<p><b><a href="default2.asp" target="_blank">Link Two</a></b></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: pls check Edits seciton.

Comment: Do you want these colors to persist? Since you use `target="_blank"` it will open the link in a separate tab/window so it's possible to change the color of just the link that you click on using jQuery, but when you go to another page and return both links will return to being the same color. To persist the colors I believe you would have to use cookies. Also what application are you using? I don't see any code to handle an OnClick event...